# Connecting Ubuntu 11.10 to Samsung LCD TV over HDMI , gives screen in green and lila

Tags: 11.10, hdmi, colors

I have a Dell 5720 laptop with  ubuntu 11.10.
I can't connect to my  Samsung LCD TV  (over Marantz nr 1601 AV).
Audio is  ok  but  the  pictures are displayed in  two colours: green and lila !

Please  send  me  a  massage how  can I fix this problem !

Thanks  a lot.

I am very confused because  I do not do anything however  it comes(seldom) to the right colouring but only for a while(5minutes) and returns to the green-lila picture again
when I do something else  for example surfing with firefox  or starting other 
programs !
The settings : resolutions of laptopscreenplay  and TV are  the same and I did 
not change the colour profile as  well .
My laptop  screen  is HD+  truebright (1600x900) and my  TV SAmsung 1280x720
I have no idea what to do my HDMI connection to make  right with the colours!
How can I fix this situation  to  gain a stable colouring ?

Answer (score 1):

it may be a hardware issue: switch cables or unplug and re-plug again

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the colouring has not changed with unplug and replug again .Ichanged my HDMI cabel too.It is very interesting but sometimes came the right colouring back for a short time however I have never changed any setting !The 5.1 AC stream (Dolby sound ) is OK not but the picture!There is always two basic colour :green  and lila  and sometimes it changes to other two colours : green&orange! Iwould be very happy if anybody would drop me a line here what should I do ?? Thx a lot

Comment: I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 but  my problem is still the same : there is no correct (only 2 colors green&lila) color transverring over HDMI port! what shell I do ?

Comment: Thanks God I have changed my Kernel version from 3.2  to 3.6  and my color problem vanished! Huh.....HDMI driver OK  for 15 Minutes !